# MS Teams Android app not supporting HTML5 <video> tag controls capabilities

Tags: android, html5-video, android-webview, microsoft-teams

**Task:** I'm currently building a Microsoft teams tab wherein I require to play some solution videos, based on the user's search (changing the src of source tag).

**Problem Statement:** Microsoft teams android app is not supporting the native HTML5 video tag controls, like fullscreen(showing disabled), picture-in-picture(no-option), playback-speed(no option). The same code is working as expected on iOS and web MS teams app.

**Solutions Tried:** I tried using various video players like videojs, fluentui/react-northstar -  tag. All had the same issue.

**Code Snippet:**

```
      <video id="video_player" controls preload="metadata" controlsList="nodownload" 
          className="ms-Grid-col ms-sm12 ms-md12 ms-lg12">
          <source id="video_player_source" src="" type="video/mp4"/>
      </video>
```

Comment: It's looks like the video tag is broken on Android and it is not supported to android device.

Comment: We have raised bug for the same and concerned team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any update.